# Validate Datatype of a List in C#? If possible by LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a List which contain ID(int),Name(String),Salary(decimal).list is already populated with 90 rows.I want to validate all the ID that they not having other than integer value so as for salary and name. Is it possible by LINQ. i am using framework 4.5 with VS2012 any quick solution.

Comment: if id is of type int, how can it hold non integral value?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
class MyClass
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    decimal Salary;
}

...

bool IsValid(MyClass myInstance)
{
   int nameInt;
   return ((myInstance.Salary % 1) == 0) && // check salary
          int.TryParse(myInstance.Name, out nameInt); // check name
}

...

 // verify that all items in list are valid
List<MyClass> myList = ...
bool listValid = myList.All(IsValid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check Salary here

.Where( x = > x.Salary.Equals( (int) x.Salary)

Is a bit of a dirty one where we cast it to int (losing the decimal places, then see if its the same as the previous value.

or

.Where(x => x.Salary.Equals(Math.Round(x.Salary,0))

Or just use Int32.TryParse - not sure why you want to do this with linq.

Comment: Well the above should work. The .Where clause will return the ones which don't pass the validation.